# How can I get a hash list of all minted NFTs for a CMV2 using Python?

Tags: anchor, nft, python, jsonrpc-api, candy-machine-v2

I am trying to fetch a hash list of all minted NFTs from a given Candy Machine V2 ID. Ideally I'd like a method that returns similarly to the [Magic Eden mint list tool](https://magiceden.io/mintlist-tool).

My suspicion is that I could start by getting account data using an RPC but as far as decoding this, I have no clue what to do.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's not Python but Jacob explains it well here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70597753/how-to-find-all-nfts-minted-from-a-v2-candy-machine

Comment: Thanks, I did take a look at this before asking here but I was unsure how I could use this given a custom RPC URL as well as it not being Python (as you said). @BryonM